# BayesSearchCV of LGBMregressor: how to weight samples in both training and CV scoring?

Tags: lightgbm, scikit-optimize, bayessearchcv

While optimizing LightGBM hyperparameters, I'd like to individually weight samples during both training and CV scoring. From the [BayesSearchCV docs](https://scikit-optimize.github.io/stable/modules/generated/skopt.BayesSearchCV.html), it seems that a way to do that could be to insert a [LGBMregressor `sample_weight`](https://lightgbm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pythonapi/lightgbm.LGBMRegressor.html) key into the BayesSearchCV `fit_params` option.  But this is not clear because both BayesSearchCV and LGBMregressor have `fit` methods.

To which `fit` method is the BayesSearchCV `fit_params` going?  And is using `fit_params` really the way to weight samples during both training and CV scoring?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the [documentation](https://scikit-optimize.github.io/stable/modules/generated/skopt.BayesSearchCV.html) I believe `fit_params` is passed as an argument upon BayesSearchCV() instantiation, not when the .fit() method is called.